# What is the most efficient way to get all results from Elasticsearch?

Tags: search, elasticsearch, lucene

I need to get all the hits for a query with along with the score. I don't care if the results are sorted in any order or not. Is there anyway to make elastic search the sorting part to make the process more efficient. The scroll API disables the sorting but when using it with "sort" : ["_doc"] it also skips the scoring process.
Are there any other sort order than ["_doc"] that might work in this case ?

EDIT: setting Track_score to true did make elasticsearch return the scores but didn't really make it faster; the took time is still almost the same. Any ideas as to why that might be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-request-scroll.html): "If you want the scoring to happen, even without sorting on it, set the track_scores parameter to true".